# error: There are no versions available for the package 'Azure.Identity' when trying to install Azure Identity client library

Tags: .net, nuget

Exploring .NET and the various Azure related .NET libraries by following  [Quickstart: Azure Key Vault secret client library for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net?tabs=azure-cli)

I have everything in place, the .NET 8 SKD, Azure CLI, VSS code, however when following the steps where I have to install the **Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets** and **Azure.Identity** packages both fail with

```
C:\Users\g-adam\HW2\key-vault-console-app> dotnet add package Azure.Identity
  Determining projects to restore...
  Writing C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1oj3bz.tmp
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET for code signing.
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET for timestamping.
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Azure.Identity' into project 'C:\Users\me\HW2\key-vault-console-app\key-vault-console-app.csproj'.
error: There are no versions available for the package 'Azure.Identity'.
```

I don't see here [Azure Identity client library for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity/1.11.0-beta.1)
 any other prerequisites.

At first I was wondering if that's because I have not referenced the package in the project file but reading here it looks like it is not needed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package#description

What am I doing wrong ?